# MySQL: Matching inexact values using "ON"

Tags: mysql, join, rounding

I'm way out of my league here...

I have a mapping table (table1) to assign particular values (value) to a whole number (map_nu). My second table (table2), is a collection of averages (avg) for each user (user_id).

(*I couldn't figure out how to properly  make a markdown table, please feel free to edit!*)

```
table1:          table2:
(value)(Map_nu)  (user_id)(avg)
----             -----
1      1         1   1.111
1.045   2        2   1.2
1.09    3        3   1.33333
1.135   4        4   1
1.18    5        5   1.389
1.225   6        6   1.42
1.27    7        7   1.07
1.315   8
1.36    9
1.405   10
```

The value Map_nu is a special number that each user gets assigned according to their average. I need to find a way to match the averages from table2 to the closest value in table1. I only need to match to the 2 digit past the decimal, so I've added the Truncated function

```
SELECT table2.user_id, map_nu
FROM `table1`
JOIN table2 ON TRUNCATE(table1.value,2)=TRUNCATE(table2.avg,2)
```

I still miss the values that don't match the averages exactly. Is there a way to pick the nearest truncated value or even to round to the second decimal? Rounding up/down wont matter as long as its applied to all values the same.

I am trying to have the following result (if rounded up):

```
(user_id)(Map_nu)  
----
1   4
2   6
3   6
4   1
5   10
6   11
7   3
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an awkward database design. What is the data representing and what are you trying to solve? There might be a better way.

Comment: there are elements that I've edited it out to simplify, but I think I've over simplified. I'll make some edits to the question. Let me know if it that makes it any clearer.

Comment: This may not be fair to the other kind contributors but- granted this question was from a year ago and I've long moved-on, it's clear that this question was not thorough enough or asking the right information. Selecting this answer! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

i think you might have to do this in 2 separate queries. there is no 'nearest' operator in sql, so you can either calculate it in your software, or you could use

```
select map_nu from table1 ORDER BY abs(value - $avg) LIMIT 1
```

inside a loop. however, that cannot be used as a join function as it requires the ORDER and LIMIT which are not valid as joins.

another way of looking at it is it seems that your map_nu and value are deterministic in relation to each other - `value = 1 + ((map_nu - 1) * 0.045)` - so maybe you could make use of that fact and calculate an integer based on that equation? assuming that relationship holds true for all values of map_nu.

Comment: Unfortunately the relationship does not hold throughout the Mapping Table. I'm going to make some edits to clarify, let me know if you have any other ideas. Thanks

Comment: i think your only choice is to do it inside a loop then.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe do something like...

```
SELECT a.user_id, b.map_nu, abs(a.avg - b.value)
FROM
table2 a
join table1 b
left join table1 c on abs(a.avg - b.value) > abs(a.avg - c.value)
where c.value is null
order by a.user_id
```

Doesn't actually produce the same output as the one you were expecting for (doesn't do any rounding). Though you should be able to tweak it from there. Above query will produce the output below (w/ data you've provided):

```
user_id  map_nu  abs(a.avg - b.value)
-------  ------  --------------------
      1       3    0.0209999999999999
      2       5                  0.02
      3       8               0.01833
      4       1                     0
      5      10                 0.016
      6      10    0.0149999999999999
      7       3                  0.02
```

Beware though if you're dealing with large tables. Evaluate the explain of the above query if it'll be practical to run it within MySQL or if better to be done outside it.

Note 2: Will produce duplicate rows if there are `avg` values that are equi-distant to `value` values within `table1` (Ex. if `value` for `map_nu`'s 11 and 12 are 2 and 3 and someone get's an `avg` of 2.5). Your question doesn't really specify what to do for that so you might want to take that into account.

Comment: I'm working on this while thinking about your suggestion. But- for future reference (I'm new to Stock Overflow)- what is the quick way to use Markdown and make a table like the one you have above?

Comment: I... uh, copy-pasted it from sqlyog and indented it to make it a code sample XD

Answer (score 0):

Its taking a little extra work, but I figure the easiest way to get my results will be to map all values to the second decimal place in table1:

```
1      1
1.01    1
1.02    1
1.03    1
1.04    1
1.05    2
1.06    2
1.07    2
1.08    2
1.09    3
1.1     3
1.11    3
1.12    3
1.13    3
1.14    4
...
```

Thanks for the suggestions! Sorry I couldn't present the question more clear.